# Does run_coroutine_threadsafe only hold a weak reference to its task?

Tags: python-asyncio

The current docs for [asyncio.create_task](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task) say:

> Important: Save a reference to the result of this function, to avoid a task disappearing mid-execution. The event loop only keeps weak references to tasks.

The docs for [asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe) do not have this warning. However, looking at the code, I can't see a (non-cyclic) strong reference being made once `create_task` has been invoked on the event loop. Are the docs just missing this? Do I risk my coroutine not running if I do not keep a strong reference to the future returned by `run_coroutine_threadsafe`? If not, where is the strong reference being kept?

(I have tried to force the task to be freed by calling `gc.collect()` but for some reason I can't even reproduce the known problem with `create_task`, let alone test whether `run_coroutine_threadsafe` has the same issue.)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else wondering this, I have an unofficial official answer that, yes, the weak reference warning applies to all relevant asyncio APIs, not just the one documented one. Hopefully this will get translated into an official official answer via docs at some point.